# Adding value to property inside an object.

Tags: php

I am wandering why this does not add an array value to the object.

```
<pre>
<?php

class people_names{
  public $children_names     = ["hanna", "danny", "toddy"];
  public $teen_names         = ["shewit", "rahel", "elizabeth"];
  public $old_people_names   = ["douglas", "bob", "michael"];
}
$names = new people_names;
$children = $name->children_names[] = "ninja"; 

var_dump($name->children_names);
```

Surely, there must be a way to add a name for `$children_name`

I tried `$children = $name->children_names[] = "ninja";` and `$children = $name->children_names = "ninja";` but that ninja is not getting added.

What could be the problem and solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_push`:

```
array_push($names->children_names, "ninja");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = new people_names;
$children = **$name**->children_names[] = "ninja";
```

Shouldn't you be accessing $names as it's the object you created?

EDIT: Forgot ->

```
<pre>
<?php

class people_names{
  public $children_names     = ["hanna", "danny", "toddy"];
  public $teen_names         = ["shewit", "rahel", "elizabeth"];
  public $old_people_names   = ["douglas", "bob", "michael"];
}
$names = new people_names;
$children = $names->children_names[] = "ninja"; 

var_dump($names->children_names);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP < 5.4 I recommend you do:

```
class people_names{
  public $children_names     = array("hanna", "danny", "toddy");
  public $teen_names         = array("shewit", "rahel", "elizabeth");
  public $old_people_names   = array("douglas", "bob", "michael");
}
```